# Cassandra 3.11.3 and RHEL 7 compatibility

Tags: cassandra, rhel7

Am trying to run Cassandra v3.11.3 on RHEL 7 system.
But facing memory errors while trying to start Cassandra.

Facing following error:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x0000000080000000, 1073741824, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 1073741824 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /../../../hs_err_pid16347.log
```

hs_err_pid16347.log

```
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 1073741824 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# Possible reasons:
#   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
#   The process is running with CompressedOops enabled, and the Java Heap may be blocking the growth of the native heap
# Possible solutions:
#   Reduce memory load on the system
#   Increase physical memory or swap space
#   Check if swap backing store is full
#   Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
#   Decrease number of Java threads
#   Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
#   Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
# This output file may be truncated or incomplete.
#
#  Out of Memory Error (os_linux.cpp:2760), pid=16347, tid=0x00007f7a61dec700
#
# JRE version:  (8.0_212-b04) (build )
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.212-b04 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Core dump written. Default location: /../logs/core or core.16347
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007f7a5800dae0):  JavaThread "Unknown thread" [_thread_in_vm, id=16349, stack(0x00007f7a61dad000,0x00007f7a61ded000)]

Stack: [0x00007f7a61dad000,0x00007f7a61ded000],  sp=0x00007f7a61deb520,  free space=249k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.so+0xa7ffb2]  VMError::report_and_die()+0x2e2
V  [libjvm.so+0x4cae47]  report_vm_out_of_memory(char const*, int, unsigned long, VMErrorType, char const*)+0x67
V  [libjvm.so+0x8c0ed0]  os::pd_commit_memory(char*, unsigned long, unsigned long, bool)+0x100
V  [libjvm.so+0x8b85ff]  os::commit_memory(char*, unsigned long, unsigned long, bool)+0x1f
V  [libjvm.so+0xa7c2ac]  VirtualSpace::initialize(ReservedSpace, unsigned long)+0x20c
V  [libjvm.so+0x5cf3e6]  Generation::Generation(ReservedSpace, unsigned long, int)+0x96
V  [libjvm.so+0x4d4b80]  DefNewGeneration::DefNewGeneration(ReservedSpace, unsigned long, int, char const*)+0x30
V  [libjvm.so+0x8e24ef]  ParNewGeneration::ParNewGeneration(ReservedSpace, unsigned long, int)+0x2f
V  [libjvm.so+0x5d0d26]  GenerationSpec::init(ReservedSpace, int, GenRemSet*)+0x3d6
V  [libjvm.so+0x5bbbaf]  GenCollectedHeap::initialize()+0x20f
V  [libjvm.so+0xa4326a]  Universe::initialize_heap()+0x16a
V  [libjvm.so+0xa43553]  universe_init()+0x33
V  [libjvm.so+0x613000]  init_globals()+0x50
V  [libjvm.so+0xa24cc5]  Threads::create_vm(JavaVMInitArgs*, bool*)+0x4e5
V  [libjvm.so+0x68c691]  JNI_CreateJavaVM+0x51
C  [libjli.so+0x7f44]  JavaMain+0x84
C  [libpthread.so.0+0x7ea5]  start_thread+0xc5
```

Did check "free -m" and there is enough memory available but still this error related to memory, what could be this related to? The -Xmn1G defined here.

Thinking enough memory available did try checking "ulimit -a" and updated as per this link recommendation https://serverfault.com/questions/662992/java-on-linux-insufficient-memory-even-though-there-is-plenty-of-available-memor
Rebooted the system and tried again to start Cassandra but still facing the same issue. Are there any additional settings at system level which needs to be updated here?

Also can anyone please share Cassdandra 3.11 and Operating System compatibility matrix?

Comment: We are running DSE 6.7.4 (the latest) which is Apache 3.11.X with RH 7.6 and everything works fine. Our jvm.options we have configured Xmx and Xms to 16G (hosts have 32GB of memory). What is your host configuration for memory and jvm options?

Comment: Thank you for the help. Mine is RH 7.7 and host has 32GB total memory, with Xmx and Xms to 3G which failed so changed Xmx & Xms to 1G and even 500M but nothing seems working and hence makes me think it is not related to memory but might be some system settings.

Comment: You're probably not giving it enough heap to start up.  Set Xmx and Xms to 8G, and Xmn to at least 2G (unless you're using G1GC, then don't set Xmn at all).

Comment: I agree, try going the other way. I don't think your host is running out of memory, rather your jvm is running out of memory. 3G is low. I'd try 8G for both Xmx and Xms and see if it starts. Never used Xmn, but we do use G1Gc

Comment: Thanks Aaron & Jim. I am using G1 GC here, actually did try setting Xmx and Xms to 6G and Xmn to 1G but no success, so these settings would not work. Got some breakthrough here and looks like my JVM is running out of memory because of other process on host, I will get back here and if that's the root cause then doesn't look like issue with Cassandra startup.